# Problema con objeto singleton php

Tags: php, sql, orm, singleton

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño ORM en php, me estoy basando en Eloquent.
El problema que tengo es que si necesito hacer 2 consultas seguidas de un mismo modelo, en la segunda consulta me toma los parametros de la primer consulta
Ejemplo

```
$cartGuest = Cart::where('ip', getRealIP())->get();
$cart = Cart::where('client_id', client()->id)->get();
```

las consultas me regresan lo siguiente
consulta 1

```
SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip = ?
```

consulta 2

```
SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip = ? client_id = ?
```

en la consulta 2 solo debería tomar el campo client_id y no el campo ip

los objetos se construyen de la siguiente manera

```
public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
{
    $class = get_called_class();
    $instance = singleton($class);
    $instance->attributes = [];
    $instance->bindings = [];
    return call_user_func(array($instance, $name), ...$arguments);
}

public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    $class = get_called_class();
    $instance = singleton($class);
    $instance->attributes = [];
    return call_user_func(array($instance,  $name), ...$arguments);
}
```

espero haberme explicado y me puedan ayudar a solucionarlo.

Gracias

Comment: la segunda consulta esta mal ... deberia ser: WHERE ip = ? AND client_id = ?

Comment: en donde AND puede ser el operador logico AND o cualquier otro que cumpla con tu necesidad...

Comment: el otyro problema es que no sabemos que ORM estas usando me parece que falta codigo y mas contexto de que hace el sistema

Comment: Me pregunto por qué haces dos consultas y no una.